# Оставить только строки с максимальным значением

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть датафрейм с сотрудниками компаний и с их (сотрудников) днями рождения:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'company': {0: 'AAA', 1: 'AAA', 2: 'AAA', 3: 'AAA', 4: 'AAA', 5: 'BBB', 6: 'BBB',
                                         7: 'BBB', 8: 'CCC', 9: 'CCC', 10: 'CCC', 11: 'CCC', 12: 'CCC'},
                             
                             'employee': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e', 5: 'f', 6: 'j',
                                          7: 'k', 8: 'l', 9: 'm', 10: 'n', 11: 'o', 12: 'p'},
                             
                             'bday': {0: '13.02.1992', 1: '25.05.1993', 2: '22.07.1994', 3: '14.08.1994', 4: '16.09.1996',
                                      5: '02.10.1996', 6: '22.07.1993', 7: '01.05.1995', 8: '01.01.1996', 9: '01.02.1993',
                                      10: '04.05.1995', 11: '06.07.1999', 12: '01.01.1991'}})
df['bday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['bday'], dayfirst=True)
df.groupby(['company', 'employee']).max()
```

Не получается оставить строки только с самыми молодыми сотрудниками по каждой компании.
Нужно, чтобы вывод был таким:

```
AAA     a        1992-02-13
BBB     f        1996-10-02
CCC     l        1996-01-01
```

Как мне оставить в df только строки с максимальной датой по группе 'company'?

Пытаюсь

```
df['yongest'] = df.apply(lambda x: max(i['bday'] for i in df if i['company'] == x['company']))
```

но ругается

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res = df[df.groupby('company')['bday'].transform("max") == df['bday']]
```

```
   company employee       bday
4      AAA        e 1996-09-16
5      BBB        f 1996-10-02
11     CCC        o 1999-07-06
```

Answer (score 3):

Сортируем фрейм по датам рождения. Группируем по компаниям. В каждой группе выбираем последнюю строку - это и есть самый молодой сотрудник.

```
df = df.sort_values('bday').groupby('company').agg('last')
```

```
        employee       bday
company                    
AAA            e 1996-09-16
BBB            f 1996-10-02
CCC            o 1999-07-06
```